# jQuery mobile - progress bar (loading bar) not working (stopped) until all elements are rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

My problems is that when a page loads, a progress bar (or loading bar) is stopped until all the data (from the server) is parsed and all the UI elements are rendered. I tried to put locations of the code differently which initializes the progress bar, such as in the pageshow(), pagecreate(),

```
$("#dataHome").on('pagecreate', function() {    

    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); // jQM loading bar widget
    ...
}
```

and even $(window).load(function){ ... }

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        var html = "<img src='css/images/ajax-loader.gif' />";
        $('#loader').append(html);
    });
</script>
```

But, Both ways didn't work for me. The loading bar didn't move while it started to rotate after all UI elements are rendered.

Is there any way for me to make the progress bar working first while the data is parsed and before all elements are loaded?

Sorry for not putting my code.. It's too ugly and hard to make it short.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var ajax_call = serviceURL;

        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: ajax_call,
           async: false,
           dataType: "json",
           beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", LOADING_MSG , false);
           },
           success: function(response){

            }
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();            
        });
```